# HID API unable to build test gui

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, hidapi

After following the whole readme procedure for the hid api, when trying to run 'make' from the 'hidtest/' directory I get the "make: Nothing to be done for `all'." error. I have no idea what is causing this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the make file specific for your os.

I used make -f Makefile.mac for my Mac.

Greg